# If the result is null show a column of what I input in where in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check when my `where in` value is empty. How can I do that?

**Example**

```
select emp_id, name from employee where emp_id in(
'C0003',
'C0005',
'C0019',
'C0100'
)
```

And for example the `C0019` is not exist, I want to fill the emp_id as what I input on where and the name is `null`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a derived table and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select v.emp_id, e.name
from (values ('C0003'), ('C0005'), ('C0019'), ('C0100')
     ) v(emp_id) left join
     employee e
     on e.emp_id = v.emp_id;
```